# About tight rational bounds

Tags: bounded-variation

Suppose we have rational functions $f$, $g$, and $h$ defined for all natural numbers $n$ such that $f \leq g \leq h$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can we prove that there is no rational functions $f_1$ and $g_1$ such that  $f \leq f_1 \leq  g \leq g_1\leq h$ ?

Knowing that the field $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, that is for any $q_1$ and $q_2$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, there always exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_1< q< q_2$. Is this already sufficient to show that my previous question's implication is false; that is there are always rational functions $f_1$ and $g_1$.

Now suppose a function $g$ not defined by any elementary operation but the range $R$ of $g$ is a subset of  $\mathbb{Q}$, did my previous question now possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not for all natural $n$ rather, but for all defined $n$. thanks

Comment: @Kenneth could you say more?  What kind of defined n? And are you referring to the rational functions or the more general functions?

Comment: @BettyMock, since rational functions have variables in the denominator, that is in this case its $n$.so when the polynomial in the denominator becomes zero for that particular $n$ that means its not part of the domain of $f$, thats why its for all defined n of the functions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misinterpreting what you mean by rational function (usually this refers to a function that is the ratio of two polynomials).

Consider $f(n) = n-2, g(n) = n,$ and $h(n) = n+2$. These are defined for all natural numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the desired inequality holds.

Now use $f_1(n) = n-1$ and $g_1(n) = n+1$ to obtain the inequalities you were trying to avoid. (!)

Moreover, from the phrasing of your question: why not just take $f_1 = f$ and $g_1 = g$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense that is there is no integer between 1 and 2. so there exists a way to order it, unlike in $\mathbb{Q}$.would the case be different to rational functions?

Comment: @KenethAdrian Can you write down your definition of "rational function"?

Comment: @ Benjamin Dicknam: Rational functions are functions where two polynomials say P and Q where $Q \neq 0$ such that $\frac{P}{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$, $g$, and $h$ be rational functions of $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

$$f(n) \leq g(n) \leq h(n).$$

In general, there *is always* a family of rational functions $f_1, g_1$ that satisfies 
$$f(n) \leq f_1(n) \leq g(n) \leq g_1(n) \leq h(n);$$
we can simply take
$$f_1(n) = \frac{f(n) + g(n)}{2},$$
and
$$g_1(n) = \frac{g(n) + h(n)}{2}.$$

Comment: @ Dris: Suppose we have a collection of rationals, say $S$ such that $S \subset \mathbb{Q}$? where $S$ cannot be expressed as ration of two polynomials...and this set represents the function $g$. how can we show then that $f_1$ and $g_1$ still exists..?

Comment: @KenethAdrian, if $f, g, h \in \mathbb{Q}$, then

$$f_1(n) = \frac{f(n) + g(n)}{2} \in \mathbb{Q},$$

and

$$g_1(n) = \frac{g(n) + h(n)}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}.$$

Comment: Suppose there exists rational functions $f$ and $h$ such that it bounds $S$ the range of $g$. if rationals $f_1$ and $g_1$ exists such that its the only rational functions that bound $g$ and we say they are the "tight" bounds of $g$. How can we show such situation? since we are concluding that there is no other way?

Comment: Hold on.  What is true is that $f(n) \leq g(n) \leq h(n)$, right?  This *is true* for each $n$.  I guess you have to be more careful when you say "*Suppose there exist functions $f$ and $h$ such that [they] bound $S = g(n) \subset \mathbb{Q}$.*"

Comment: Additionally, I am not quite sure if "*tight* bounds" correspond to "*best-possible* bounds", but I will assume that they do.  In this case, if you want to show that $f_1$ and $g_1$ are tight bounds for $g(n)$, you can do this by proving that, if you assume the negation of your original hypotheses, then you either get $g(n) < f_1$ or $g(n) > g_1$.

Comment: @ Dris: Yes..:)

Comment: So contradiction is the approach?. Thank you @Dris